# CORS ERROR when using Axios to make CSRF token in Vite

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vite

```
export const apiRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AXIOS_BASEURL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
  }
})
export const apiCheckPermission = (data) => apiRequest.post('/checkPermission', data)
```

```
const getToken = async () => {
  await apiGetToken.get('/getCSRFToken').then((res) => {
    document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content = res.data
    loginSet._token = res.data
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', res.data)
  })
}
```

```
const checkPermission = async () => {
  const formData = new FormData()
  Object.keys(loginSet).forEach((e) => {
    formData.append(e, loginSet[e])
  })
  try {
    await getToken()
    const data = await apiCheckPermission(formData)
    if (data.data.result === true) {
      router.push({
        name: 'overView'
      })
    } else {
      img.value = data.data.captcha.img
      userData.captcha_key = data.data.captcha.key
      sessionStorage.setItem('captcha_key', userData.captcha_key)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Vite: ^4.1.4+Vue3

Back-end: laravel 9+nginx

The getToken Function needs to be conducted to acquire CSRF Token in the log in page.

However, after acquiring CSRF Token and conduting checkPermission Function, it shows:

*cess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/api/checkPermission' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Please share us your suggestion, thanks!

The Back-end engineer had tried to fix Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and it is okay in both postman and the old project using AJAX to test.

Regarding adding 'X-Requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest', in Headers or modifying 'Content-Type', it just doesn't work.